# Adsense in FireFox not showing

Tags: asp.net, firefox, adsense

I came accross something very strange when i was testing my pages in FireFox.
The Adsense blocks are commented out (green) in firefox.

It does render however properly when i paste all the rendered code in a blank aspx page in the same project without using masterpage.

http://picpaste.com/problem.jpg

Here's a picture of the problem. As you can see on one of the pages the script code is green. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. the page was sent as application/xhtml+xml which has to be text/html. Although not defined as such it did send it with that content-type.

Any solutions on how to get AdSense work on firefox with content-type application/xhtml+xml?

Comment: Try updating your question (click 'edit') instead, so people see it. Or accept this as one solution and open another question. (Can't tell how related they are.)

Answer (score 1):

The version that doesn't work correctly is defined as XHTML. This means that `<!--` will always open a comment, even inside a script tag.

You can remove the comment tag as it isn't needed, and you should put the contents of the script tag in a CDATA block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
// script goes here
]]>
</script>
```